# How to embed image in body using php?

Tags: php, image, email, phpmailer

I tried embedding image using cid in php to send emails. But, instead it goes as an attachment file. Kindly tell me if I am doing anything wrong.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['sendMail'])) {
        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        require 'credential.php';
    
        $invoice = new PHPMailer;
        $invoice->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $invoice->Host = 'mail.funprimetechnology.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $invoice->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $invoice->Username = EMAIL;                 // SMTP username
        $invoice->Password = PASS;                           // SMTP password
        $invoice->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $invoice->Port = 587;  

        $invoice->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['full_name']);
        $invoice->addAddress($_POST['email']);     // Add a recipient

        $invoice->addReplyTo(EMAIL);
    
        $invoice->isHTML(true); 

        $invoice->AddEmbeddedImage('images/FP.png', 'FP');

        $invoice->Subject = "FunPrime Customer Quote Request";
        $invoice->Body = "<p>Test</p>;
        $invoice->Body .= "<img src='cid:FP'>";;

        $invoice->AltBody = $_POST['message'];

        if(!$mail->send() or !$invoice->send()) {
            header ('Location: unsuccessful.html');
        } else {
        header ('Location: thanks.html');
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You have a missing closing quote: `$invoice->Body = "<p>Test</p>;`

Comment: Why not just echo out the link of the image on your server, e.g. `http://yourdomain.com/images/test.jpeg` in the `<img>` tag?

Comment: I tried it earlier but didn't work. But, now it seems to working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

$invoice->AddEmbeddedImage("some_picture.png", "my-attach", "some_picture.png", "base64", "image/png");